# Universal property of Isbell duality

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, 2-categories, universal-property

Let's take $\mathrm{C}$ be a category, let's have an adjunction $(\mathcal{O} \dashv \operatorname{Spec}) : \mathrm{CoPresheaves(C)}  \leftrightarrows \mathrm{Presheaves(C)}$. One such adjunction is the Isbell duality adjunction. Is there a good description for a 2-categorical universal property of Isbell duality among all the possible adjunctions between presheaves and co-presheaves on $\mathrm{C}$?

Comment: The adjunctions between $[C, \mathbf{Set}]$ and $[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ correspond to the functors $C^\text{op} \times C \to \mathbf{Set}$, so an equivalent question to yours is whether the hom-functor $C^\text{op} \times C \to \mathbf{Set}$ has a 2-categorical universal property. It's an odd question, and I wonder whether it's really what you want to ask. In any case, there are multiple descriptions and characterizations of Isbell conjugacy (as it's traditionally called) in http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/36/12/36-12abs.html ; perhaps one of those will help with whatever you're doing.

Comment: I think what I was looking for was the lemma 2.2 in that paper. But I have to read more of that.